# Creating permalinks for jquery + php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, permalinks

So I have this site that dynamically posts content using jquery and php.  I would like to know how to generate permalinks.  I think I could do it, but I dont even know what I should be searching for on google.  You can see the site at www.eataustineat.com.

For example, I would like a link like eataustineat.com/claypit to that would go directly to the video review, instead of having to to search for it and then click the link.

I will describe the how the site works on a basic level:

1. first the user selects the "All Restaurants tab" in the content slider, then jquery slides to the third frame.
2. Next, a user selects a link from a list.  This list is generated by sql queries in php, while javascript pushes the result of the php to a specific div.
3. When a user selects a link, jquery slides to the second slide.  Once again, php runs a query while javascript pushes the content to a specific div.  As a result, the user never leaves the index page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on how your website works. The ideal thing that I have in my mind at the moment is:

1. Decide a unique way to find your video (could be a title, a file name, an id: **must not change**), if you are using a database it's a column with a value different for each entry
2. Create a webpage that accept as a parameter (not optional) (possibly a $_GET parameter, not a post) that unique key and fills it's content with entry's data (the video review hopefully)
3. Now the permalink will be yourwebsite/yourwebpage?myparam=myvalue

Normally the permalink is the numerical id referred to that entry (thinking about databases in this case)

**Edit 1:** If what you mean is "moving the webpage to the link" (and not creating it), maybe you should ignore my answer, I didn't understand the question so.
What suggested Tadeck, if this is the case, is good

**Edit 2:** What about if, following the keylines I given you to create a permalink, you pass this value to the homepage and on page load you fire the event through the click() function (so it's like if the user clicks on the link, fires everything that you need, even the scroller thing)
Obviusly you need to give an ID to each  tag, but I don't think it's a big problem (just use directly your "permalink value" as an id

The alternative in using click() method, is: give to the slider function a name so you can call it instead of waiting the click event only, expecially this part

```
$('.cross-link').live("click", function(){
```

You'll have to replace function() with a named function

then you will call, on page load, that function + ajaxpage('result.php?id=9', 'results2') + ajaxpage('videoloader.php?id=9') completely emulating the click event in this case.

You still need however an id in the a tag to find out which is the link

Comment: the site uses a jquery content stroller.  The second "frame" will have the information im after.  And yes, the content is in a mysql database.

Comment: Mhhh so it's actually a javascript question, not a php question, right? I'm having problems in understanding what you want, sorry

Comment: no problem. if you go to my site, go to "all restaurants" and select the "Austin Eats Food Tours" link, you will be navigated to a new section.  That section - with video and all - is what I would like to create a permalink to.

Comment: Try with what I suggested in my answer

Comment: lol. that's actually exactly what I starting implementing.  Instead of permalinks, I just pass parameters through the url and jquery acts on them.

Comment: Good, hope you can continue your job now. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should search for one (or both) of the following points:

1. [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.c2.a0method) and [`onStateChange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIWebProgressListener#onStateChange%28%29) - preferred, nicest and probably what you are looking for,
2. [`location.hash`](http://programming.top54u.com/post/Javascript-Location-Hash-with-Example.aspx) and [`onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) - probably easier to implement (does not require you to support it on server side and works in older browsers too), but in this case you would get URL like `http://eataustineat.com/#!claypit` instead of `http://eataustineat.com/claypit`.

In this first case you would need to make sure server side scripting / configuration will invoke proper state within JS, when visited eg. by entering URL (`http://eataustineat.com/claypit`).

Comment: are there examples of this?  also, it says that IE is not supported.